# Как сделать хорошую разметку в коде, чтобы картинки не разъезжались на разных устройствах?

Tags: java, android, canvas, bitmap, разметка

Делаю меню в мобильной игре (меню в виде картинок)(ниже представлен один из элементов)

```
 menu_n = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.m);
 menu_nBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(menu_n,350, 100, false);

 canvas.drawBitmap(menu_nBitmap,(width / 2 - proceed_Width / 2 +50), 0, null);
 canvas.drawText("меню", width/2+proceed_Width/10, 70, mPaint);
```

Выравниваю всё, чтобы на устройстве, на котором тестирую, выглядело хорошо. Проблема в том, что как только я запускаю игру на другом устройстве или эмуляторе, всё разъезжается. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать так, чтобы меню выглядело нормально на разных устройствах

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: не могли бы вы показать визуально как это выглядит и чего вы пытаетесь добиться пожалуйста?

Comment: чтобы все выглядело "нормально" нужно использовать относительные размеры, а не +50 и координаты 70

Comment: Почитай какую-нибудь статью о том, как правильно делать разметку для андроида.

Comment: @Style-7, буду очень признателен, если покажите, как именно это сделать в моём случае

Comment: @Andrew, я добавил 2 картинки, при запуске на разных устройствах

Comment: @Эникейщик, порекомендуйте, пожалуйста, что можно почитать по поводу создания разметки в коде

Answer (score 0):

Контейнеры типа ConstraintLayout, FrameLayout и т.д. можно использовать и в коде. Вам остается лишь задать LayoutParams а так же добавить туда ваши картинки, текст и фон. `layout.addView(textView)`